# How can I add the description of a module inside the module table of contant

Tags: grouping, doxygen

I have my code organized as follows

Header files:

```
 /**
 * @defgroup  alternator_controller Alternator Controller
 * @ingroup   application_layer
 * @file      alternator_controller.h
 * @{
 */
 
 /* Header code */

 /**@}*/
```

Source files:

```
/**
 * @ingroup   alternator_controller
 * @file      alternator_controller.c
 *
 */
```

This produces an table of content output like this:

[image]

I want the group description to be displayed next to the group in the index, i.e., the red letters in the image shall be changed by the module description

I have already trief placing the brief field in multiple locations without any luck.

```
 /**
 * @defgroup  alternator_controller Alternator Controller
 * @ingroup   application_layer
 * @file      alternator_controller.h
 * @brief DESCRIPTION HERE IS NOT DISPLAYED
 * @{
 * @brief DESCRIPTION HERE IS ALSO NOT DISPLAYED
 */
  
  /* Header code */

  /**@}*/
```

Any idea how can this be achieved (if possible at all)?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to have text with the `@defgroup` like:

```
 /**
 * @defgroup  alternator_controller Alternator Controller
 * @ingroup   application_layer
 * @{
 * @brief DESCRIPTION HERE IS DISPLAYED
 */

  /* Header code */

  /**@}*/
```

and this will result in:

[image]